# Relax Ng list patterncomma separated

Tags: xml, relaxng

I am using `Relax Ng` to validate `XML` file

In my XML file I have a tag with several values separated by comma

```
<mytage>01,02,03,04<mytage>
```

I can use `<List>` pattern in the .rng file but it matches a whitespace-separated sequence not comma-separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be specified using `<param name="pattern">` with a regular expression; for example:

```
<data type="string" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
  <param name="pattern">[0-9][0-9](,[0-9][0-9])*</param>
</data>
```

Or in the compact syntax:

```
xsd:string {
    pattern = "[0-9][0-9](,[0-9][0-9])*"
}
```

If you want to make it part of a `<choice>`:

```
<choice>
    <data type="string" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
      <param name="pattern">[0-9][0-9](,[0-9][0-9])*</param>
    </data>
    <data type="string" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
      <param name="pattern">…</param>
    </data>
</choice>
```

Or in the compact syntax:

```
(    xsd:string {
        pattern = "[0-9][0-9](,[0-9][0-9])*"
    }
|   xsd:string {
        pattern = "…"
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , can I use the <choice> tag with this solution ? , I mean using the <param name="pattern"> and the <choice>

Comment: @divo yes you can use `<choice>` with it—see the updated answer